# Link to the start of post page comment are (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to link from the main page of my wordpress theme which shows my recent posts to there individual comment areas within there post pages. So that when the link on the main page is clicked the user is taken straight to the comment area of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link:

```
http://www.example.org/example-post#comments
```

Will lead you directly to the comments section if there is a name or ID called **comments**.

Comment: This sort of works but once the page finish loading it jumps to the top of page, do you know what may be causing this?

Comment: That sounds strange. Probably some JavaScript interfering in some way. Do you have a link to your website?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the other plugins and seeing if that still happens?

Comment: I just tried visiting the website with and without JavaScript enabled. It works just fine without JavaScript, so try Howlin's suggestion to disable the plugins and reactivate them one by one.

Comment: Also setting the width/height for images is nice to do as well, so the page doesn't jump as the image loads.

Comment: Ok when I deactivated mailchimp social wordpress plugin it fixed the problem, do you have any idea why the plugin could be causing the problem?

Comment: Not sure if you should create a new question or rename the current one, because we are discussing completely different problem than what we did before.